# How to calculate bandwidth requirments based upon flows per minute (fpm)?

Tags: bandwidth, netflow

I want to know how can one calculate bandwidth requirements based upon flows and viceversa.

Meaning if I had to achieve total of 50,000 netflows what is the bandwidth requirement to produce this number? Is there a formula for this. I'm using this to size up flow analyzer appliance. If its license says supports 50,000 flows what does this means. How more bandwidth if i increase I would lose the license coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Most applications and appliances list flow volume per second, so you are asking what the bandwidth requirement is to transport 50k netflow updates per second:

For NetFlow v5 each record is 48 bytes each with each packet carrying 20 or so records, with 24 bytes overhead per packet.  This means you'd use about 20Mbps to carry the flow packets.  If you used NetFlow v9 which uses a template based format it might be a bit more, or less, depending on what is included in the template.

However, if you are asking how much bandwidth you can monitor with 50k netflow updates per second, the answer becomes more complex.  In our experience monitoring regular user networks (using google, facebook, etc) an average flow update encompasses roughly 25kbytes of transferred data.  Meaning 50,000 flow updates per second would equate to monitoring 10Gbps of traffic.  Keep in mind that these are very rough estimates.

This answer may vary, however, if you are monitoring a server-centric network in a datacenter, where each flow may be much larger or smaller, depending on content served.  The bigger each individual traffic session is, the higher the bandwidth will be you can monitor with 50,000 flow updates per second.

Finally, if you enable sampling in your NetFlow exporters you will be able to monitor much more bandwidth.  Sampling will only use 1 in every N packets, thus skipping many flows.  This lowers the total number of flow updates per second needed to monitor high-volume networks.